# Difference between HttpContext.Current.User and this.User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What's the difference between `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` ? Sometimes they appear on my code and sometimes they don't(so i have to use the other one). Do they mean the same thing or there should be a specific sort of "context" for me to use them?

I have this code that i use from one of my classes:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {

    return 0;

}
```

So what's `this` and `HttpContext` ? I know `this` refers to a specific instance but what about the `HttpContext` ?

Comment: Hover over `this` / `HttpContext`, Right-click, **Go To Definition**

Comment: It is open source, so you should check the code. They should be the same.

Comment: Oh right, thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `this.User.Identity.IsUthenticated` are the same thing but with difference usage.

You use 
 `this.User.Identity.IsUthenticated` inside a controller but
if you are outside controller and you need to know if the user is authenticated you use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: The context one might return null, so be warned.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `HttpContext.` over `this.` in controllers?

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all. Both HttpContext.Current.User and Controller.User are the same.

"this" is your Controller, and the BaseController has the User properties.

this goes something like this.

```
 public class Controller
 {
      public User { get { return HttpContext.Current.User; } }
 }

 public class YourController : Controller
 {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
           return this.User.Identity.Name;
      }
 }
```